# How do I see currently executing web request on IIS 8

Tags: iis-8

In IIS 7, I would click on "worker process" then "View Current Request" to see all the requests currently being executed.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732518(v=WS.10).aspx

In IIS 8, I do not see this option.  Is there something I need to set up on IIS 8?

Edit: I tried running inetmgr as administrator as well.

Comment: TCPVIEW is an awesome tool that will show u what u want.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

There wasn't any UI hints, but was able to turn it on as a feature under server manager.

Server Manager -> Add Roles.

- Web Server (IIS)

  - Web Server

    - Health and Diagnostics

      - Request Monitor

Comment: That was still hard to find. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/sB2y9Wd.png Now how do I get to it once installed?

Comment: So it's installed, where do I run it from?

Comment: I was pulling my hair out because I had lost this functionality!!  Thanks!!

Comment: Request Monitor is installed, but I when I select 'View current requests', nothing shows up?
Do I have to enable/configure anything else?

Comment: @Evert Request Monitor is only useful for broken or slow requests. It can't give you any information about requests that complete properly.

Comment: @Evert Distracted... "View current requests" shows broken/slow requests. You can use logman to start an ETW session using the "IIS: Request Monitor" source for other requests.

Comment: For anyone else who was confused, this is a Windows feature that must be installed before it's available in IIS Manager. In Windows 10, the feature can be enabled/disabled through the Apps & Features control panel at: Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Health and Diagnostics > Request Monitor.

Answer (score 50):

The required features can be installed with PowerShell.

IIS Manager:

```
Install-WindowsFeature Web-Mgmt-Tools
```

Request Monitor:

```
Install-WindowsFeature Web-Request-Monitor
```

With these features installed, run IIS Manager, browsing to the Worker Processes section shown in the screenshot below. From the list of Worker Processes, either double click on the process of interest to view currently executing requests or use the right-click context menu.

[image]

The back/forward arrows to the left of the address bar can be used to navigate back and forth between the list of requests and worker processes. The `alt+left arrow` / `alt+right arrow` keys perform the same actions.

Comment: pressing F5 would refresh the list too

Answer (score 19):

I had to do this from an elevated command line

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list requests
```

If you want to see requests exceeding more than 5 seconds

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list requests /elapsed:5000
```

In a loop (assuming you are in `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\`

```
for /l %x in (,,) do (appcmd list requests /elapsed:5000 & timeout 2)
```

Answer (score 12):

This show's the steps to install it. From https://portal.ektron.com/KB/10396/:

To run it after it's installed you will need to find the "Worker Process" icon on the server settings in IIS Manager.

[image]

Another good option with ASP.net is to go to task manager, right click on the process and select "Create Dump File" then download and double click on the created .dmp file to load it into Visual Studios debugger. Then look thru the threads and their call stacks to see where all the requests are being executed. **This method allows you to see exactly what the requests are doing (infinite loops, deadlocks, etc.)**

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question and @JonathanK answer is correct, but I would like to add a couple of data in case it is necessary to use DISM.

Install using DISM

`dism.exe /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:IIS-RequestMonitor`

To translate from Powershell to DISM

`Get-WindowsFeature <featurename> |% { $_.AdditionalInfo.InstallName }`