# asp.net crash: IIS8 Requests Execting increases and CPU stays low

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, iis

I'm stuck figuring out what will be the next trouble shooting step to take or research.

I've got one web application running on one IIS8 webserver. Lately we are struggling with the performance of the webapplication. This morning the webapplication 'crasht' again. With this I mean that it didn't respond to any new requests.

Because Perfmon is your friend, I fired off the following counters:

- Processor Time (%)
- Requests Executing
- Requests/Sec

See the image I've included.[image]

What I find interessting is that "Requests Executing" only increased at this point. And... the CPU was not running 100% to get rid of all these requests.

As I'm the main developer of this web application, I already optimized many high-CPU webpages.
With this SO thread I'm hoping to find the bottle neck. Maybe with tips for extra logging. Application code analysis etc. I can provide more information about the setup or application when needed.

Hope you can help. Many thanks in advance.

Some specifications:

- Windows Server 2012R2
- IIS8
- Intel Xeon Quad core CPU
- Total of 4 gig memory
- ASP.net 4.0 web application

User specs:

- Google Analytics Real Time visitors between 100-500
- Normal requests/sec average of 30
- 'Peak' requests/sec of 200 / 300

EDIT:
I run a Perfmon Data Collection Set for about a hour. Exactly at the moment when the website crashed. I used the tool [PAL](https://pal.codeplex.com/) to analyze it. It only had many warnings about the memory being below 5%.
This memory issue is clearly an issue we will be resolving soon.

Another thing I noticed is that the list of "current requests" in IIS8 was enormous. It contained hundreds of "current requests". I would expect these requests to reach a time out value and send a request Timed Out to the users.

Here is a print-screen of the current healthy situation:
[image]

This list was infinite long.

And, again another thing I just noticed, was one request taking more then 10 minutes(!) to deliver a byte[] to a user. The 'state' was SendResponse. I persume this user was on a low-bandwitdh device. As long as this user is downloading - one workerprocess is taken. How should we prepare this long pending requests?

Comment: Oke - I found a feature that can be enabled that is called **"Request Monitor"**. SO-link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15622626/167196. 
I think that if I enable that feature, and I will be able to look into the current (pending) requests, I might see something that causes this issue.

Comment: Because I'm not sure if Enabling that feature will cause a reboot - I wait until I get an acceptable time frame to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at PAL at https://pal.codeplex.com/ - this will guide you in collecting a number of stats and then analyse them for you.

Along with CPU, other bottlenecks are memory, network, and disc IO. PAL should help you in collecting the appropriate stats - it has several pre-defined sets for e.g. Web Server, DB Server, etc.

Comment: Thank you for this valuable answer. I didn't knew this existed. I'm going to give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Good luck! If you have any problems with it post them here as a new question, or maybe use the Discussion tab at codeplex - looks reasonably active.