# How to get the current list of Worker Request from IIS using C#?

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, request, worker

I am writing the code for a RESTful web service status page. I was wondering if there is away to get the current request from IIS into C#.

I am using IIS 7.0 and the info I want is under

> IIS > Worker procecces > *ASP.NET v4.0* > Requests

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`GetRequests`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.workerprocess.getrequests(v=vs.90).aspx) method of the [`WorkerProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Web.Administration.WorkerProcess(v=vs.90).aspx) type. This type is located in the [`Microsoft.Web.Administration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Web.Administration(v=vs.90).aspx) assembly which can be installed using this [unofficial nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Administration/) or by adding a reference to this dll `%WinDir%\System32\InetSrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll`

Example:

```C#
using (ServerManager manager = new ServerManager())
{
    while (true)
    {
        var requests = manager.ApplicationPools
                                .Where(pool => pool.Name == "FooPool")
                                .SelectMany(pool => pool.WorkerProcesses)
                                .SelectMany(wp => wp.GetRequests(10));

        Console.WriteLine(requests.Count());
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Note: You need to have the IIS Request Manager feature enabled and also run with a user with sufficient permissions. See [How do I see currently executing web request on IIS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621509/how-do-i-see-currently-executing-web-request-on-iis-8)

Comment: Is this possible in local IIS sever? I get an error saying *System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.*
 for the method ``GetRequests().``