# how to get all IIS worker Processes list into my Console Application?

Tags: c#, iis, console-application

i have a server in which i published a asp.net web site.
i want to create a console application which show how many worker processes are in the IIS. please any help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868022/how-to-get-the-current-list-of-worker-request-from-iis-using-c

Comment: Do you need all processes inside server or just related to IIS pipeline (modules)?

Comment: yes i need all processes inside iis

Answer (score 1):

You can add this reference in project `Microsoft.Web.Administration` assembly which can be installed using this [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Administration/) or by adding a reference to this dll `%WinDir%\System32\InetSrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll`

```
using (ServerManager manager = new ServerManager())
{
        var requests = manager.ApplicationPools
                                .SelectMany(pool => pool.WorkerProcesses).Count();
        Console.WriteLine(requests);
}
```

Comment: i used this code but it throw below error .
Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {2B72133B-3F5B-4602-8952-803546CE3344} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Comment: Try to run with Administrator. I test this on VS 2015.

Comment: Did you have IIS installed on your system where you test it ?

Comment: no i don't, IIS is installed  on another machine(window server 2016).

Comment: Run this code on where you installed IIS. It will work there.
You except output on your system while the output source IIS not present. That's why it give error to you.