# Get list of IIS hosted site URL's using C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to find is there a way to get the list of site URL's hosted on a server IIS. The purpose of doing this is, We have number of Web API's, DNN Web applications hoted in the IIS. So, I am developing a console application which gets the list of IIS hosted application URL's and do the HTTP call to check whether the site is up and running or not based on the HTTP status.

Please suggest if there's a way to do the above requirement.

Comment: This looks to be a job for powershell. Are you sure, that there is no cmdlet that can handle this? Have you checked `Get-IISSite`?

Answer (score 1):

you could use powershell - something like this

```
Get-WebBinding | % {
    $name = $_.ItemXPath -replace '(?:.*?)name=''([^'']*)(?:.*)', '$1'
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Name = $name
        Binding = $_.bindinginformation.Split(":")[-1]
    }
} | Group-Object -Property Name | 
Format-Table Name, @{n="Bindings";e={$_.Group.Binding -join "`n"}} -Wrap
```

you would then call the powershell from you C# code

Answer (score 0):

or via the cmd line:

```
cd c:\Windows\system32\inetsrv

appcmd list sites > c:\myBindings.txt
```

very succinct!

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can look for fetching the list of IIS worker process(which is per applicationpool) and its running status. To fetch the list of IIS worker process you can refer following link [how to get all IIS worker Processes list into my Console Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379819/how-to-get-all-iis-worker-processes-list-into-my-console-application)